# Could detect ay running remote java application in debugger?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Have next problem cannot run debugger.
What i do. I put breakpoint on controller `return gradebook.getStudents();`
click right button on mouse -> choose debug us -> Remote Java Application
[image]

Than appear problem "Sorry, could not detect any running remote java applications. Try search again.

[image]

Than i go to run Configurations and add this `"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,suspend=y"`

[image]

2. but i have problem that you can see in console after i click apply and run
3. also i create new configuration, that have Host:localhost, port:8099, source:Junit-name my app, and checkbok in debug

[image]

How right set up this application, please say me!

When i run debug -> java application in main class, i have next

[image]

Comment: The first screenshot shows a menu item of a plugin you have installed. From the icon I would guess it's JBoss Tools. The third screenshot shows a Spring Boot launch configuration. And the last screenshot shows a launch configuration to debug a remote Java application listening at port 8099, not 8000 as defined in your Spring Boot application. If you want to debug a Java application, right-click the class with the main method and choose _Debug As > Java Application_. Similar for a JUnit test: _Debug As > JUnit Test_. To debug a remote application, it has to be started with the right arguments.

Comment: Tnx, could you see and say, what i must to do next, please!

Comment: That depends what kind of application you want to debug and whether it's a remote or local application. For a local Java application it's just setting a breakpoint, right-click the class with the main method and choose _Debug As > Java Application_ (or just hitting _Debug_ button assuming the class with the main method is open).

Comment: i do same thing, and when i run main class, Debug As -> Java Application, i have problem "Source not found", i attached picture in my post, please bro, i need your help, i need that debugger

Comment: Looks like you run your application only with a JRE, not with a JDK. Make sure you have configured a JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ for the Java version you use in your project.